# Prevent multi level Li horizontal breaking

Tags: html, css, treeview

I have the following code for Creating Tree using LI 
- Problem : when the tree nodes get big more than the screen width the li is breaking to new line 
for all tree nodes level , so i need to prevent li breaking and makes the page scroll
This is my Code :

```
[https://jsfiddle.net/naadydev/xq8a3ztz/2/][1]
```

Comment: if they are not broken into lines, there should be a horizontal scrollbar, otherwise the overflow content will be hidden (which isn't usable for user)

Comment: u tried overflow:auto?

Comment: You've described what you don't want it to do, but not what you expect it to do.

Comment: I want the page to be scroll that what i want and the li expand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `white-space: nowrap;` to the containing `ul` and change the display of children `li`s to 
    `inline-block;` .

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/5CadG/

```
#list {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.tree li {
    /* float: left; */ /* REMOVD */
    display: inline-block;
    /* rest of your styles */
}
```

Comment: @user179326 You are welcome! Glad to be of help to you.